# trying to write single cycle verilog code?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to write a single cycle mips verilog code which only contains selected instructions, to pass a simple test, it took two days for me to write below code but I checked instruction per instruction but getting to branch( first branch) instruction I really became desperate( the new pc value doesn't update correctly ).I would be so appreciated by any suggestion from you.

PS: the instructions before first branch are executed correctly.

here is the main code

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps
// R Format funcs
`define ADDU 6'b100001
`define ADD 6'b100000
`define SUB 6'b100011
`define AND 6'b100100
`define XOR 6'b100110
`define NOR 6'b100111
`define SLT 6'b101010
`define MULT 6'b011000
`define SLTU 6'b101011
`define MULTU 6'b011001
`define JALR 6'b001001
`define JR 6'b001000
`define MFHI 6'b010000
`define MFLO 6'b010010

// I & J Format op
`define ADDI 6'b001000
`define ADDIU 6'b001001
`define ORI 6'b001101
`define XORI 6'b001110
`define ANDI 6'b001100
`define SLTI 6'b001010
`define SLTIU 6'b001011
`define LUI 6'b001111
`define LW 6'b100011
`define SW 6'b101011
`define BEQ 6'b000100
`define BNE 6'b000101
`define J 6'b000010
`define JAL 6'b000011

// ALU OP
`define alu_add 4'b0000
`define alu_sub 4'b0001
`define alu_and 4'b0010
`define alu_or 4'b0011
`define alu_xor 4'b0100
`define alu_nor 4'b0101
`define alu_sltu 4'b0110
`define alu_slt 4'b0111
`define alu_addu 4'b1000




module single_cycle_mips(

   input clk,
   input reset 
);

   wire alu_z;
   reg [3:0] alu_op;
   reg [1:0] aluSrcB ,RegDst ;
   reg [2:0] WD_e;
   reg [4:0] Regno , flag=0;
   reg aluSrcA, SE_ZEn, rf_wrt;
   reg pc_wrt, ir_wrt, IorD, mar_wrt ,mult_s ,is_s,mem_wrt;


   wire [31:0] rf_rd_1, rf_rd_2, alu_result ,s1,s2,mem_addr,mem_write_data,mem_read_data;
   reg [31:0] pc, MemtoReg, ir,mar, aluB , aluA ,A ,B ,HI ,LO;


   // CONTROLLER Starts Here



   wire [5:0] ir_op = ir[31:26];
   wire [5:0] funct = ir[5:0];


   always @(ir) begin : MAIN

      //nxt_state = 'bx;

      alu_op  = 'bx; aluSrcB = 'bx; aluSrcA = 'bx; SE_ZEn = 'bx;
      rf_wrt = 1'b0; pc_wrt = 1'b0; ir_wrt = 1'b0; WD_e = 'bx;
      mem_wrt = 1'b0; mult_s = 'bx; mar_wrt = 1'b0; Regno = 'bx;
      is_s = 'bx; RegDst = 'bx ;


            IorD = 0;
            ir_wrt = 1'b1;    // load IR by memory data
            //aluSrcA = 1'b0;      //
            //aluSrcB = 2'b01;      //
            //alu_op = `alu_addu;    //
            //pc_wrt = 1'b1;    // pc <- pc + 4
            pc = pc + 4;
         #8


            case(ir_op)
               6'b000000:begin             // R-format
                  if(funct == `MFHI) begin                
                    WD_e = 3'b010;
                    rf_wrt = 1'b1;
                    RegDst = 2'b01;
                    //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                    end
                  else if(funct == `MFHI) begin               
                    WD_e = 3'b011;
                    rf_wrt = 1'b1;
                    RegDst = 2'b01;
                    //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                    end
                  else if((funct == `JALR) || (funct== `JR)) begin
                    A =rf_rd_1;
                    if(funct == `JALR) begin
                    rf_wrt = 1'b1;
                    WD_e = 3'b100;
                    RegDst = 2'b01;
                    end
                    pc = A;
                    end
                  else begin
                  A = rf_rd_1;
                  B = rf_rd_2;
                   #3
                  rf_wrt = 1'b1;
                  aluSrcA = 1'b1;
                  aluSrcB = 2'b00;
                  WD_e = 3'b001;
                  RegDst = 2'b01;

        case(funct[5:0]) 
                    `ADD: begin alu_op = `alu_add; end 
                    `ADDU: begin alu_op = `alu_addu; end
                    `SUB: begin alu_op = `alu_sub;   end 
                    `AND: begin alu_op = `alu_and;   end 
                    `XOR: begin alu_op = `alu_xor;   end 
                    `NOR: begin alu_op = `alu_nor;  end 
                    `SLTU: begin alu_op = `alu_sltu;  end 
                    `SLT: begin alu_op = `alu_slt;   end 
                    `MULT: begin 
                        if(flag <=18 && flag!=0)
                        flag= flag+1;
                        else if(flag == 18) begin
                        HI <= #0.1 s2;
                        LO <= #0.1 s1;
                        flag = 0;
                        end
                        else if(flag==0) begin
                        mult_s = 1'b1;
                        is_s = 1'b1;
                        end
                        end
                    `MULTU: begin
                        if(flag <=18 && flag!=0)
                        flag= flag+1;
                        else if(flag == 18) begin
                        HI <= #0.1 s2;
                        LO <= #0.1 s1;
                        flag = 0;
                        //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                        end
                        else if(flag==0) begin
                        mult_s = 1'b1;
                        is_s = 1'b1;
                        end
                        end

        endcase

                  end
                  end
               `ADDI ,`ADDIU ,`ORI ,`XORI ,`ANDI ,`SLTI, `SLTIU: // I format
                    begin
            A = rf_rd_1;
            #3
            rf_wrt = 1'b1;
            aluSrcA = 1'b1;
            aluSrcB = 2'b10;
            WD_e = 3'b001;
            RegDst = 2'b00;
            case(ir_op)
                `ADDI:begin
            SE_ZEn =1'b1;   
            alu_op = `alu_add;
            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                end
                `ADDIU:begin
            SE_ZEn =1'b0;   
            alu_op = `alu_addu;
            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                end
                `ANDI:begin
            SE_ZEn =1'b1;
            alu_op = `alu_and;
            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                end     
                `ORI:begin
            SE_ZEn =1'b0;
            alu_op = `alu_or;
            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                end     
                `XORI:begin
            SE_ZEn =1'b0;
            alu_op = `alu_xor;
            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                end     
                `SLTI:begin
            SE_ZEn =1'b1;
            alu_op = `alu_slt;
            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                end 
                `SLTIU:begin
            SE_ZEn =1'b0;
            alu_op = `alu_sltu;
            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                end 
        endcase
                    end 
                `LUI: begin
                    WD_e = 3'b101;
                    rf_wrt = 1'b1;
                    RegDst = 2'b00;
                    end
                `LW: begin
            A = rf_rd_1;
            mar_wrt = 1'b1;
            aluSrcA = 2'b1;
            aluSrcB = 2'b10;            
            SE_ZEn = 1;
            alu_op = `alu_add;
            #3
            IorD = 1;
            #8
            rf_wrt = 1'b1;
            WD_e = 3'b000;
            RegDst = 2'b00;
            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                    end
                `SW: begin
            A = rf_rd_1;
            B = rf_rd_2;
            mar_wrt = 1'b1;
            aluSrcA = 1'b1;
            aluSrcB = 2'b10;            
            SE_ZEn =1'b1;
            alu_op = `alu_add;
            #3
            IorD = 1;
            ir_wrt = 0;
            mem_wrt = 1;
            #4 begin IorD = 0; mem_wrt = 0; ir_wrt = 1; end
            //disable MAIN;

            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                    end
                `BEQ ,`BNE: begin
            A = rf_rd_1;
            B = rf_rd_2;
            aluSrcA = 1'b1;
            aluSrcB = 2'b00;
            alu_op = `alu_xor;
            #3
            if( ((alu_z == 0) && ((ir_op)== `BEQ) ) || ((alu_z == 1) && ((ir_op)== `BNE)))
            disable MAIN;
            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
            else
            begin
            SE_ZEn =1'b1;
            aluSrcA = 1'b0;
            aluSrcB = 2'b11;
            alu_op = `alu_add;
            pc_wrt = 1'b1;
            //nxt_state = FETCH1;
            end
                  end   
                `J: begin
                    pc = {7'b00000,ir[25:0]};
                    //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                    end
                `JAL: begin
                    rf_wrt = 1'b1;
                    RegDst = 2'b10;
                    WD_e = 3'b100;
                    pc = {7'b00000,ir[25:0]};
                    //nxt_state = FETCH1;
                   end
             endcase



   end

   // CONTROLLER Ends Here

   // DATA PATH Starts Here

   always @(posedge clk)
      if(reset) begin
         pc <= #0.1 32'h00000000;
         IorD = 0;
         ir_wrt = 1'b1;
         end
      else if(pc_wrt)
         pc <= #0.1 alu_result;

   always @(posedge clk) if(ir_wrt)  ir <=  #0.1 mem_read_data;

   always @* if(mar_wrt) mar <= #0.1 alu_result;

   assign mem_write_data = B;

   assign mem_addr = IorD ? mar : pc;



   wire [31:0] SZout = SE_ZEn ? {{16{ir[15]}}, ir[15:0]} : {16'h0000, ir[15:0]};


   always @(*) begin
      case (aluSrcB)
         2'b00: aluB <= B;
         2'b01: aluB <= 32'h4;
         2'b10: aluB <= SZout;
         2'b11: aluB <= SZout << 2;
      endcase
      case (aluSrcA)
         1'b0: aluA = pc;
         1'b1: aluA = A;

      endcase
      case(RegDst)
        2'b00: Regno <= ir[20:16];
        2'b01: Regno <= ir[15:11];
        2'b10: Regno <= 31;
        endcase
      case(WD_e)
        3'b000: MemtoReg <= mem_read_data;
        3'b001: MemtoReg <= alu_result;
        3'b010: MemtoReg <= HI;
        3'b011: MemtoReg <= LO;
        3'b100: MemtoReg <= pc;
        3'b101: MemtoReg <= {ir[15:0],16'h0000};
        endcase

end   

    my_alu alu(
      .aluA(aluA),
      .aluB(aluB),
      .aluOp(alu_op),

      .aluResult(alu_result),
      .aluZero(alu_z));

    reg_file registers(
   .clk(clk),
   .write(rf_wrt),
   .WR(Regno),
   .WD(MemtoReg),
   .RR1(ir[25:21]),
   .RR2(ir[20:16]),
   .RD1(rf_rd_1),
   .RD2(rf_rd_2));   

    async_mem mem(
    .clk(clk),
    .write(mem_wrt),
    .address(mem_addr),
   .write_data(mem_write_data),
   .read_data(mem_read_data));



 multiplier u1( 
.clk(clk),
.start(mult_s),
.is_signed(is_s),
.a(A),
.b(B),
.s1(s1),
.s2(s2));

   // DATA PATH Ends Here



endmodule

module my_alu(
   input [31:0] aluA,
   input [31:0] aluB,
   input [ 3:0] aluOp,
   output reg[31:0] aluResult,
   output        aluZero
);

   always @(*)
      case(aluOp)
         `alu_add : aluResult <= #2 aluA + aluB;//begin if( aluA[31] == aluB[31]) aluResult <= #2 aluA + aluB;
                    //else  aluResult <= #2 aluA[31] ? ~aluA + aluB + 1'b1 : aluA + ~aluB +1'b1; end          // add
         `alu_addu : aluResult <= #2 aluA + aluB;
         `alu_sub : aluResult <= #2 aluA + ~aluB + 1'b1;      // sub
         `alu_and : aluResult <= #2 aluA & aluB;
         `alu_or  : aluResult <= #2 aluA | aluB;
         `alu_nor : aluResult <= #2 ~(aluA | aluB);    // ?? ~ ( aluA | aluB )
         `alu_xor : aluResult <= #2 aluA ^ aluB;
         `alu_sltu : aluResult <= #2 aluA < aluB ? 1 : 32'h00000000;
         `alu_slt: begin
            if( aluA[31]!=aluB[31])begin 
            if( aluA[31]== 1)
            aluResult <= #2 1;
            else if( aluA[31]== 0)
            aluResult <= #2 32'h00000000;
            end
            else if( aluA[31]==aluB[31] ) begin
            if (aluA[31]== 0)
            aluResult <= #2 aluA < aluB ? 1 : 32'h00000000;
            else if( aluA[31]== 1)
            aluResult <= #2 (~aluA+1'b1) < (~aluB+1'b1) ? 1 : 32'h00000000;
         end
         end
      endcase

   assign aluZero = ~ (|aluResult);

endmodule


module async_mem(
   input clk,
   input write,
   input [31:0] address,
   input [31:0] write_data,
   output [31:0] read_data
);


   reg [31:0] mem_data [0:1023];

   assign #7 read_data = mem_data[ address[31:2] ];

   always @(*)
      if(write)
         mem_data[ address[31:2] ] <= #2 write_data;

endmodule

   module reg_file(
   input clk,
   input write,
   input [4:0] WR,
   input [31:0] WD,
   input [4:0] RR1,
   input [4:0] RR2,
   output [31:0] RD1,
   output [31:0] RD2
);

   reg [31:0] rf_data [0:31];

   assign #2 RD1 = rf_data[ RR1 ];

   assign #2 RD2 = rf_data[ RR2 ];

   always @(*) begin
      if(write) begin
         rf_data[ WR ] <= #0.1 WD;

         `ifdef DEBUG
         if(WR)
            $display("$%0d = %x", WR, WD);
         `endif

      end
      rf_data[0] <= #0.1 32'h00000000;
   end

endmodule
```

and here is the hex of the test code:

```
[0x000000]  0x34080000  # ori $t0, $zero, 0 ($t0 = $zero | 0)
[0x000004]  0x24090060  # addiu $t1, $zero, 96 ($t1 = 96)
[0x000008]  0x3403DEAD  # ori $v1, $zero, -8531 ($v1 = $zero | -8531)
[0x00000C]  0xAD030080  # sw $v1, 128($t0) (mem[$t0 + 128] = $v1)
[0x000010]  0x2129FFFF  # addi $t1, $t1, -1 ($t1 = $t1 + -1)
[0x000014]  0x25080004  # addiu $t0, $t0, 4 ($t0 = $t0 + 4)
[0x000018]  0x00631020  # add $v0, $v1, $v1 ($v0 = $v1 + $v1)
[0x00001C]  0x00621026  # xor $v0, $v1, $v0 ($v0 = $v1 ^ $v0)
[0x000020]  0x3843BEEF  # xori $v1, $v0, -16657 ($v1 = $v0 ^ -16657)
[0x000024]  0x1409FFF9  # bne $t1, $zero, -7 (if ($t1 != $zero) goto -7)
[0x000028]  0x20080004  # addi $t0, $zero, 4 ($t0 = 4)
[0x00002C]  0x20090060  # addi $t1, $zero, 96 ($t1 = 96)
[0x000030]  0x01294821  # addu $t1, $t1, $t1 ($t1 = $t1 + $t1)
[0x000034]  0x01294821  # addu $t1, $t1, $t1 ($t1 = $t1 + $t1)
[0x000038]  0x0109502A  # slt $t2, $t0, $t1 (if ($t0 < $t1) $t2 = 1 else $t2 = 0)
[0x00003C]  0x1140000E  # beq $t2, $zero, 14 (if ($t2 == $zero) goto 14)
[0x000040]  0x00085820  # add $t3, $zero, $t0 ($t3 = $t0)
[0x000044]  0x8D0C0080  # lw $t4, 128($t0) ($t4 = mem[$t0 + 128])
[0x000048]  0x000B502A  # slt $t2, $zero, $t3 (if ($zero < $t3) $t2 = 1 else $t2 = 0)
[0x00004C]  0x11400007  # beq $t2, $zero, 7 (if ($t2 == $zero) goto 7)
[0x000050]  0x216DFFFC  # addi $t5, $t3, -4 ($t5 = $t3 + -4)
[0x000054]  0x8DAE0080  # lw $t6, 128($t5) ($t6 = mem[$t5 + 128])
[0x000058]  0x01CC502B  # sltu $t2, $t6, $t4 (if ($t6 < $t4) $t2 = 1 else $t2 = 0)
[0x00005C]  0x11400003  # beq $t2, $zero, 3 (if ($t2 == $zero) goto 3)
[0x000060]  0xAD6E0080  # sw $t6, 128($t3) (mem[$t3 + 128] = $t6)
[0x000064]  0x000D5820  # add $t3, $zero, $t5 ($t3 = $t5)
[0x000068]  0x1000FFF7  # beq $zero, $zero, -9 (if ($zero == $zero) goto -9)
[0x00006C]  0xAD6C0080  # sw $t4, 128($t3) (mem[$t3 + 128] = $t4)
[0x000070]  0x21080004  # addi $t0, $t0, 4 ($t0 = $t0 + 4)
[0x000074]  0x1000FFF0  # beq $zero, $zero, -16 (if ($zero == $zero) goto -16)
[0x000078]  0x1000FFFF  # beq $zero, $zero, -1 (if ($zero == $zero) goto -1)
```

and here is the test bench:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module multi_cycle_mips__tb;

    reg clk = 1;
    always @(clk)
        clk <= #20 ~clk; //20

    reg reset;
    initial begin
        reset = 1;
        @(posedge clk);
        @(posedge clk);
        @(posedge clk);
        #1;
        reset = 0;
    end

    initial
        $readmemh("isort32.hex", uut.mem.mem_data);

    parameter end_pc = 32'h7C;

    integer i;
    always @(uut.pc)
        if(uut.pc == end_pc) begin
            for(i=0; i<96; i=i+1) begin
                $write("%x ", uut.mem.mem_data[32+i]);
                if(((i+1) % 16) == 0)
                    $write("\n");
            end
            $stop;
        end

    single_cycle_mips uut(
        .clk(clk),
        .reset(reset)
    );


endmodule
```

Comment: In ` always @(*)` use blocking (`=`) assignments and do not place delay statements in there. ie `rf_data[ WR ] <= #0.1 WD;` should be `rf_data[ WR ] = WD;`

Comment: thank you for your respond, but I don't think the problem is what you referred, as i mentioned the all instructions works till first branch, the problem is in branch and updating pc. I 'v been stuck  in bne.

Comment: Have you tried single stepping though the code?

Comment: @EugeneSh: What does "through time cycles" mean? Most simulators such as Modelsim have single stepping features. This roughly means they can run the code line by line with breakpoint capability; A useful feature for debugging the above code.

Comment: as i said, i checked instructions step by step by checking every single wave, it works pretty good till first branch( pc : 0x000024), the branch instruction works good except updating pc, it puts an irrelevant value into pc!

Comment: @EugeneSh: Actually it does, and I do it all the time. You can run through the lines of each concurrent process sequentially and analyze what that process is doing. Many simulators have -linedebug feature exactly for this!

Comment: @Luminous: It would be very helpful if you could post some waveforms.

Comment: @Luminous  sorry was not suggesting that those points were the problem, just pointing out that there is some problematic Verilog in use here which makes debugging your program harder. You also have `always @(ir)` which when synthesised will be `always @*`.

Comment: @Morgan, I do agree that debugging my code is hard, I am really sorry, firstly I used always @* instead of always @(ir) but it did not work, because by changing pc ( pc = pc+4), the always block stats again without executing any thing, by the way thank you.

Comment: @Luminous, you need to store your pc in a flip-flop, an `@(posedge clk ` triggered block, `pc=pc+1` is currently a combinatorial loop. It might work in simulation but will not work in hardware. I would try resolving these issues, the current issue may be come more obvious then.

Comment: @ Ari, I posted an snapshot, hope it help, the yellow line shows when the new value of pc is generated, ( in alu_result), and by next rising clock this value should be put into pc, but amazingly a strange value goes to pc that I don't know where it has come!

Comment: @ Ari, really sorry, I had not posted images before, the policy of site don't allow me posting images due to low reputation.

Comment: @Morgan, by now , I am facing the deadline to submit this homework( this is actually my home work), all I need know is to get the answer, I didn't mean to write synthasable code( at least my professor didn't referred!).

Comment: @Luminous, I can feel your pain, been there. Looks like a pretty big assignment you were given would not like to have to mark it. Will just point out that in module `single_cycle_mips` you have multiple processes writing to `pc`  at line 277 [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/CJx) as well as in the previous `always @*` section

Comment: @Morgan thank you for understanding me :-), honestly I just worked on instructions mentioned in test( it is a sort test), so technically pc just changes in  277 EDA Playground as you said and  pc = pc +4 in previous always @* section.( I hadn't work with  EDA Playground before,interesting), Thank you all for putting your time on solving my problem, I know it is hard to find my problem bcz I myself can't find it though I wrote it! but it was my last option, Thank you all.

Comment: @Luminous: As Morgon mentioned, assigning to `pc` should NOT happen from multiple always blocks. What you really want is to assign to a variable called `pc_next` in your combinational (not combinatorial!) section (e.g. in `J` and `JAL`). The default value of `pc_next` (i.e. If there is no jmp instruction), will be `pc + 4`.  Then set `pc <= pc_next` in the sequential section (the always block with @posedge clk).